# Class has two properties of the same name "address1"

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to create JAXB object using the below code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_transaction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthorizeRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_type")
    public String transaction_type;

    @XmlElement(name = "transaction_id")
    public String transaction_id;

    .......

    public String getTransaction_type() {
        return transaction_type;
    }

    public void setTransaction_type(String transaction_type) {
        this.transaction_type = transaction_type;
    }

    public String getTransaction_id() {
        return transaction_id;
    }       
}
```

Inner object:

```
public class Address {

    @XmlElement(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    ... getters and setters
}
```

But I get error:

```
2019-06-23 11:43:10,495 ERROR [stderr] (AuthorizeContainer-1) Class has two properties of the same name "address1"
2019-06-23 11:43:10,496 ERROR [stderr] (AuthorizeContainer-1)   this problem is related to the following location:
2019-06-23 11:43:10,496 ERROR [stderr] (AuthorizeContainer-1)       at public java.lang.String authorize.request.Address.getAddress1()
2019-06-23 11:43:10,496 ERROR [stderr] (AuthorizeContainer-1)       at authorize.request.Address
2019-06-23 11:43:10,496 ERROR [stderr] (AuthorizeContainer-1)       at public request.Address AuthorizeRequest.billingAddress
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue? Do I need to add some annotations for the Address class?

Comment: Could you provide a code where Adress class is used? I mean in AuthorizeRequest

Comment: @mslowiak here it is: https://pastebin.com/jjJSBcBz

Comment: and could you show billingAddress field in AuthorizeRequest?

Comment: @XmlElement(name = "address1")
 public String address1;

Comment: Do you have field String adress1 and class Address?  Something is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may get a similar error when trying to add a field with an instance of a class where no `@XmlAccessorType` parameter was specified.

For example, you have:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment_transaction")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AuthorizeRequest {
    ...
    private Data data;

    // getters/setters
}
```

And `Data` class structure like:

```
public class Data {
    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

But since you did not specify the `@XmlAccessorType` parameter for accessing the `Data` class fields, by default the search will be performed both by fields and by methods. So address field clashes with getAddress method.